# Serialise multidimensional boolean NumPy array to binary

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2-dimensional (or n-dimensional) array of booleans, like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype='bool')
```

I'd like to create a space-efficient binary representation of this array to store in a database, then retrieve it. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.packbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) can be used to generate a one-bit-per-value binary representation of a boolean array, and [`numpy.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) can be used to *almost* perform the opposite operation. Unfortunately it's an imperfect inverse since `packbits` discards all information about the shape (or even dimensionality) of the array and pads it with 0-valued bits to reach a complete number of bytes. As such, we also need to explicitly store the array's shape in order to be able to parse the binary representation:

```
import numpy as np

def serialize_boolean_array(array: np.array) -> bytes:
    """
    Takes a numpy.array with boolean values and converts it to a space-efficient
    binary representation.
    """
    return np.packbits(array).tobytes()

def deserialize_boolean_array(serialized_array: bytes, shape: tuple) -> np.array:
    """
    Inverse of serialize_boolean_array.
    """
    num_elements = np.prod(shape)
    packed_bits = np.frombuffer(serialized_array, dtype='uint8')
    result = np.unpackbits(packed_bits)[:num_elements]
    result.shape = shape
    return result

# Array to serialize
arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype='bool')

# Serialized representation. You need to store the shape as well as arr_bytes
# in order to be able to deserialize this later. If you know the
# dimensionality of your array in advance (e.g. you know it's 2D), you might
# want to store the shape in several columns in your database - e.g. width
# and height. Otherwise, you could serialize it with
#     shape_bytes = np.array(shape).tobytes()
# and deserialize it later with
#     shape = tuple(np.frombuffer(shape_bytes, dtype='int64'))
arr_bytes, shape = serialize_boolean_array(arr), arr.shape

# Deserialize:
arr2 = deserialize_boolean_array(arr_bytes, shape)

np.array_equal(arr, arr2)  # True
```